# Seeking for car cigarette lighter fuse

Tags: fuse-panel

[image]Good day all,
regarding the attached screenshot (Lexus RX fuse panel) can you please help me identify the car cigarette lighter fuse. Note: There are two of them available in the car.

Comment: What image? Usually there is a legend - perhaps on the inside of the lid or in the owner’s manual.

Comment: Yes there is for sure, but it's appears a litle Gibberish (Sorry i've forgot to attach the picture, now it's done)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this one a try. If it does not work then perhaps its in the interior fuse box. Its usually the same as the OBD2 and is a 20a fuse.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, am gonna have a quick check and come back to you

Comment: Hello dear, unfortunately there is no fuse installed. it's already empty. So i guess it cannot be that one. Let me point out the fact there is two cigarette lighter available in the car. One beside the radio and the other one a litle lower, below.

Comment: There's a fusebox behind the glove compartment, access is in the passenger footwell.

Comment: @LdRH5.0AMDG, then its going to be one of the fuses in the interior box. Not sure of your year but maybe this site will help: https://fuse-box.info/lexus/lexus-rx330-rx350-xu30-2003-2009-fuses

Comment: Hi @narkeleptk, thank you so much, that seems to be an amazing website. let's check then

Comment: Hi all. That was a good one. This post solved the issue. As per @narkeleptk 's link,  There is also 2 fuse, CIG & Power Outlet No 1. Thank you so much to you all.